# Understanding the proof: If $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}.$ Then, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to understand a section in the following proof, let $a_1=1$ and $$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n},$$ then, $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Here is my question: the above question was solved in [Let $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}$ .Prove that $ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{n}=\frac{1}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069879/let-a-n1-sqrta-1a-2-cdotsa-n-prove-that-lim-limits-n-rightarrow), by taking that $a_{n+1}^2=a_{n}^2+a_n.$ Please, can you show me how $a_{n+1}^2=a_{n}^2+a_n$ was gotten?

Comment: The linked question is different. It deals with a square root; your's has the _nth_ root.

Comment: Well, you can begin with $a_{n+1}^2 = a_1 + \cdots + a_n$ and $a_n^2 = a_1 + \cdots + a_{n-1}$.

Comment: @ user58697 and spaceisdarkgreen: Sorry it was a typo! I've corrected it!

Comment: @Mike they don't assume it. They prove it

Comment: @mathworker21: Sorry for the language misuse!

Comment: The question you link has a proof.  How far can you get in it?  Where do you bog down?

Comment: @saulspatz: Thanks, spaceisdarkgreen has asnswered my question!

Comment: Oh, you said what your difficulty was in the question.  I read right past it; sorry.

Comment: I shouldn't get a downvote! I only asked to get clarifications, please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$a_{n+1}^2 = a_1+\ldots +a_{n-1} + a_n= \left(\sqrt{a_1+\ldots +a_{n-1}}\right)^2 + a_n= a_n^2+a_n$$

Comment: I shouldn't get a downvote! I only asked to get clarifications, please!